# Can I automatically reset git after pull with error

Tags: git, git-bash

Sometimes when doing a git pull/merge/checkout I get an error that one or several files can not be created due to permissions. They are probably locked by some process. If the printout is a long one I might miss the error(s).

I can easily fix it by doing a `git reset --hard HEAD@{0}`

I want to avoid the situation where I miss the error and continue coding, not knowing that these files are suddenly missing. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `git status` after the pull/merge/checkout and see if any files are still outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a git alias that calls a series of commands, or a shell script: do the operation, check the exit status, if non-zero then git reset.
(But if it was me, I would just check git status, as MichaelDurrant suggests.)